# Custom Buttons with vewpager in TableLayout

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I have an App with TableLayout but i can't make the same as in design which i will put link below

[image: Screenshot]

> My XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:clipChildren="true"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea please?

Comment: you want your tabs(demo,new,..) to be display inside of toolbar?

Comment: @Wini yes same exactly like in the image above

Comment: can you post up full xml code and screenshot of what you have done till now?

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option is to create a custom view with the 3 buttons and do all the navigation by yourself.